Unable to get DevTools log in Selenium Grid
I'm using Selenium 4.26 with openJDK 11.0.2. I have a selenium grid with 10 machines each having chrome / firefox version 130 installed (which is in line with selenium 4.26 devtools support).
Problem:

In standalone mode, i can able to retrieve logs but in grid mode i was unable to generate logs and it doesn't show any errors/warnings too.

In Standalone mode itself for firefox browser, devtools logs are not generated.


    private void getNetworkLog() {
        String browserName = ReadPropertyFile.getInstance().getPropertyValue("browserName");
        try {
            DevTools devTools = null;
            // Create DevTools session
            if(ReadPropertyFile.getInstance().getPropertyValue("runMode").equalsIgnoreCase(RunModeConstants.STANDALONE_MODE) && 
                    browserName.equalsIgnoreCase(BrowserConstants.CHROME_BROWSER)) {
            devTools = ((ChromeDriver) RemoteCustomDriver.getInstance().getRemotedriver()).getDevTools();
            }else if(ReadPropertyFile.getInstance().getPropertyValue("runMode").equalsIgnoreCase(RunModeConstants.STANDALONE_MODE) && 
                    browserName.equalsIgnoreCase(BrowserConstants.FIREFOX_BROWSER)) {
                devTools = ((FirefoxDriver) RemoteCustomDriver.getInstance().getRemotedriver()).getDevTools();
                }else if(ReadPropertyFile.getInstance().getPropertyValue("runMode").equalsIgnoreCase(RunModeConstants.STANDALONE_MODE) && 
                    browserName.equalsIgnoreCase(BrowserConstants.EDGE_BROWSER)) {
                devTools = ((EdgeDriver) RemoteCustomDriver.getInstance().getRemotedriver()).getDevTools();
                }else if(ReadPropertyFile.getInstance().getPropertyValue("runMode").equalsIgnoreCase(RunModeConstants.GRID_MODE) && 
                        browserName.equalsIgnoreCase(BrowserConstants.CHROME_BROWSER)) {
                    RemoteWebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();
                    if(d instanceof ChromeDriver) {
                    log.info("Remotewebdriver is instace of chromedriver");
                    ChromeDriver c = (ChromeDriver)d;
                    devTools = c.getDevTools();
                    }
            }
            if (devTools!=null) {
                devTools.createSession();
                // Enable network logging
                devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
                // Register listener for network events
                devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), event -> {
                    log.info("Request URL: " + event.getRequest().getUrl());
                    log.info("Request headers -->" + event.getRequest().getHeaders());
                    if (event.getRequest().getHasPostData().isPresent()) {
                        log.info("POST data -->" + event.getRequest().getPostData());
                    }
                    // You can print other information from the event such as request method,
                    // headers, etc.
                });
                devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), event -> {
                    Integer statusCode = event.getResponse().getStatus();
                    if (statusCode.toString().startsWith("4")) {
                        log.info("Received status code -->" + event.getResponse().getStatus()
                                + " when hitting the url --> " + event.getResponse().getUrl());
                        log.info("Request headers -->" + event.getResponse().getRequestHeaders());
                        log.info("Response received is -->" + event.getResponse());
                    }
                    // You can print other information from the event such as response status,
                    // headers, etc.
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
        }
    }

